# Swagger require all properties

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-2.0

Given the following schema definition (which is a valid way to define required properties):

```
MySchema:
 type: object
 required: [property1, property2, property3]
 properties:
  property1:
   type: integer
  property2:
   type: integer
  property3:
   type: integer
```

Is there a way to specify that all the properties are required?

***Clarification***: I'm looking for a way to say that **all** the properties are required, without specifying it one by one.

To be even more explicit: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113049/how-to-specify-if-a-field-is-optional-or-required-in-swagger) does not answer my question.

Answer (score 4):

That's the correct way to define model properties as required and I'm not aware of any other way to specify that all the properties are required.

For parameters, the `required` attribute is a boolean (true/false) instead of a list of required parameter's name. e.g.

```
name: avatar
in: formData
description: The avatar of the user
required: true
type: file
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `additionalProperties: false` in your schema

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).