# How to show Post request model required properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am generating Swagger in a .Net Core web api and I would like to show in the swagger UI which properties in a post request body are required?

I have already tried using Data Annotations to mark which ones are required.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify if a field is optional or required in swagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113049/how-to-specify-if-a-field-is-optional-or-required-in-swagger)