# OpenAPI not empty String

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have a problem .

I created openApi request and I want to send to request not empty body

```
/test
  post:
   .
   .
   .
   requestBody:
     required:true

TestRequest
  type: object
  required:
    - testName
  properties:
    testName:
    type: string
    description: Test
```

I can send a request empty body like
{
} on postman.

How can i solve this problem .

Comment: Do these links answer your question? -- [How to specify which fields in request body (POST) are required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63944331/113116), [How to specify if a field is optional or required in OpenAPI/Swagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40113049/113116)

Answer (score 0):

Your `post` definition states that ***a*** body is required. However, you have not defined what the shape of the data is that must go into that body.

Here is an example that assumes your `TestRequest` is defined inside `components/schemas`.

```
paths:
  /test:
    post:
      description: An example referencing TestRequest
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/TestRequest'
```