# OpenAPI 3.0.1 required vs optional properties

Tags: openapi, nswag

I'm using [NSagStudio](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag) to generate a c# client for an [OpenAPI 3.0.1](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.1.html) service. Since the latest update I get an issue where a property marked as required is missing from the retrieved data and thus cannot be deserialized.

I'm trying to understand if

- The OpenAPI spec of the service is incomplete/wrong
- I've misconfigured something with NSwagStudio
- There is a bug in NSwagStudio

OpenAPI 3.0.1 service spec: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/admin-ch/CovidCertificate-Apidoc/main/open-api/api-doc.yaml

NSwagStudio configuration:

```
{
  "runtime": "NetCore31",
  "defaultVariables": null,
  "documentGenerator": {
    "fromDocument": {
      "json": "[see URL]",
      "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/admin-ch/CovidCertificate-Apidoc/main/open-api/api-doc.yaml",
      "output": null,
      "newLineBehavior": "Auto"
    }
  },
  "codeGenerators": {
    "openApiToCSharpClient": {
      "clientBaseClass": "BagCovidCertificateClientInternalBase",
      "configurationClass": null,
      "generateClientClasses": true,
      "generateClientInterfaces": false,
      "clientBaseInterface": null,
      "injectHttpClient": false,
      "disposeHttpClient": true,
      "protectedMethods": [],
      "generateExceptionClasses": true,
      "exceptionClass": "BagCovidCertificateApiException",
      "wrapDtoExceptions": true,
      "useHttpClientCreationMethod": false,
      "httpClientType": "System.Net.Http.HttpClient",
      "useHttpRequestMessageCreationMethod": true,
      "useBaseUrl": true,
      "generateBaseUrlProperty": true,
      "generateSyncMethods": false,
      "generatePrepareRequestAndProcessResponseAsAsyncMethods": false,
      "exposeJsonSerializerSettings": false,
      "clientClassAccessModifier": "internal",
      "typeAccessModifier": "internal",
      "generateContractsOutput": false,
      "contractsNamespace": null,
      "contractsOutputFilePath": null,
      "parameterDateTimeFormat": "s",
      "parameterDateFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd",
      "generateUpdateJsonSerializerSettingsMethod": true,
      "useRequestAndResponseSerializationSettings": false,
      "serializeTypeInformation": false,
      "queryNullValue": "",
      "className": "BagCovidCertificateClientInternal",
      "operationGenerationMode": "SingleClientFromOperationId",
      "additionalNamespaceUsages": [],
      "additionalContractNamespaceUsages": [],
      "generateOptionalParameters": false,
      "generateJsonMethods": false,
      "enforceFlagEnums": false,
      "parameterArrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable",
      "parameterDictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary",
      "responseArrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection",
      "responseDictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary",
      "wrapResponses": false,
      "wrapResponseMethods": [],
      "generateResponseClasses": true,
      "responseClass": "SwaggerResponse",
      "namespace": "Documedis.Clients.External.Clients.Internal",
      "requiredPropertiesMustBeDefined": true,
      "dateType": "System.DateTimeOffset",
      "jsonConverters": null,
      "anyType": "object",
      "dateTimeType": "System.DateTimeOffset",
      "timeType": "System.TimeSpan",
      "timeSpanType": "System.TimeSpan",
      "arrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection",
      "arrayInstanceType": "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection",
      "dictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary",
      "dictionaryInstanceType": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary",
      "arrayBaseType": "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection",
      "dictionaryBaseType": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary",
      "classStyle": "Poco",
      "jsonLibrary": "NewtonsoftJson",
      "generateDefaultValues": true,
      "generateDataAnnotations": true,
      "excludedTypeNames": [],
      "excludedParameterNames": [],
      "handleReferences": false,
      "generateImmutableArrayProperties": false,
      "generateImmutableDictionaryProperties": false,
      "jsonSerializerSettingsTransformationMethod": null,
      "inlineNamedArrays": false,
      "inlineNamedDictionaries": false,
      "inlineNamedTuples": true,
      "inlineNamedAny": false,
      "generateDtoTypes": true,
      "generateOptionalPropertiesAsNullable": false,
      "generateNullableReferenceTypes": false,
      "templateDirectory": null,
      "typeNameGeneratorType": null,
      "propertyNameGeneratorType": null,
      "enumNameGeneratorType": null,
      "serviceHost": null,
      "serviceSchemes": null,
      "output": "BagCovidCertificateClientInternal.Generated.cs",
      "newLineBehavior": "Auto"
    }
  }
}
```

My issue occurs with this element:

```
    IssuableRapidTestDto:
      type: object
      properties:
        code:
          type: string
          description: Code of rapid test as string.
          example: "1232"
        display:
          type: string
          description: Manufacturer and display name of rapid test as string.
          example: "Abbott Rapid Diagnostics, Panbio Covid-19 Ag Rapid Test"
        validUntil:
          type: string
          description: Deadline after which the rapid-test can no longer be used to
            establish a certificate.
          format: date-time
          example: 2022-01-06T00:00:00+01:00
```

Which results in following class being generated:

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "13.15.5.0 (NJsonSchema v10.6.6.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0))")]
    internal partial class IssuableRapidTestDto
    {
        [...]

        /// <summary>
        /// Deadline after which the rapid-test can no longer be used to establish a certificate.
        /// </summary>
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("validUntil", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public System.DateTimeOffset ValidUntil { get; set; }

        [...]
    }
```

My issue occurs because not all `IssuableRapidTestDto` have a `ValidUntil` date set, when retrieving the data.

If I remove `Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull` the deserialization works and `ValidUntil` holds `DateTimeOffet.MinValue`. As this is generated code I don't want to adapt it manually.

I'm having a hard time figuring out if `ValidUntil` is actually required or not.

Comment: `validUntil` is optional in your example. In fact, `IssuableRapidTestDto` has no required properties. See [How to specify if a field is optional or required in OpenAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40113049/113116)

Comment: Thanks, I've opened an issue on GitHub https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/3851