# How to indicate in OpenAPI that all response fields are required?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have an answer with 40 fields. I need to specify that all fields are required.

1. Option to list all fields

   - required: [field1,field2,field3 ..... field40]

Maybe there is an option to indicate that ALL fields of the answer are required.
For example allOf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`required: [field1, field2, ..., field40]` is the [only way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40113571/113116). There are no shortcuts.