# Fastify openapi 3 create alway required fields

Tags: node.js, swagger, openapi, fastify

i use @fastify/swagger and @fastify/swagger-ui,
my config

```js
import fastifySwagger from '@fastify/swagger';
import fastifySwaggerUi from '@fastify/swagger-ui';
import { FastifyInstance } from 'fastify';
import fp from 'fastify-plugin';

const swagger = async (fastify: FastifyInstance) => {
  await fastify.register(fastifySwagger, {
    mode: 'dynamic',
    openapi: {
      openapi: '3.0.3',
      info: {
        title: 'openapi',
        version: '0.1.0'
      }
    }
  });

  await fastify.register(fastifySwaggerUi, {
    routePrefix: '/openapi',
    uiConfig: {
      deepLinking: true
    },
    uiHooks: {
      onRequest: function (request, reply, next) {
        next();
      },
      preHandler: function (request, reply, next) {
        next();
      }
    },
    staticCSP: true,
    transformStaticCSP: (header) => header,
    transformSpecification: (swaggerObject, request, reply) => {
      return swaggerObject;
    },
    transformSpecificationClone: true
  });
};

export default fp(swagger);
```

my routes like this

```js
export const articleRouter = async (fastify: FastifyInstance) => {
  fastify.get(
    '/list',
    {
      schema: {
        tags: ['article'],
        summary: 'getting artilce list',
        description: 'description in routes',
        params: {
          type: 'object',
          description: 'some params',
          properties: {
            limit: {
              type: 'number',
              description: 'limit articles'
            },
            sort: {
              type: 'string',
              description: 'asc or desc'
            }
          },
          required: ['sort']
        },
      }
    },
    async (req, resp) => {
      const articles = await articleService.findArticles();
      resp.send(articles);
    }
  );
};
```

swagger screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsNub.png)

All works, but field 'limit' is alway required. Why?

Please, help me.

I'm playing with all properties in config and routes but no one helpe me.

[@fastify/swagger](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-swagger) [@fastify/swagger-ui](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-swagger-ui)

Comment: this answer might help [How to specify if a field is optional or required in OpenAPI/Swagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113049/how-to-specify-if-a-field-is-optional-or-required-in-openapi-swagger#answer-40113571) - use `required: true`

Comment: Thank you, but I saw this issue. For some reason, fields is required by default and not changing.

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in the choice of property used. I replaced `params` with `querystring`, because it's not a path parameter but a query one.